# Angular 2 + i18n + AOT not working

Tags: node.js, angular, internationalization, jit, angular2-aot

I'm developing the language change utility using buttons (`<a/>`  tags) so that the user can change the language if they click the link that contain the label of the corresponding language.

To develop it, I have taken as a reference the [QuickStart project](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) of Angular 2, I added [AOT and JIT compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), then I added the ng-xi18n module ([JIT version](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)) and finally, I added [GULP module](http://rolandoldengarm.com/index.php/2016/10/17/angular-2-automated-i18n-workflow-using-gulp) for generate files of other languages.

When I compile my project with JIT (using `npm run start`) and run it, my language change utility works fine.

The problem comes when I compile my project with AOT (using `npm run start: aot`) and I run it, my language change utility does not work.

Where is the problem?

My project ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/Paulillo16/i18n-quickstart.git)) has two `main.ts` and `index.html` - one for JIT and other for AOT.

Comment: Do you use `--base-href`?

Comment: Yes, I'm use --base-href

Comment: Can you describe further what happens when "my language change utility does not work", please. Wrong url?